# How to navigate through tables and get results by a query in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join

Having some tables where I store information about a patient and type of tests (there are 3 types of tests, those I store in other table) patient were exposed I got:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patients ( 
  ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  Name     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  Tel   VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
  Email      VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tests ( 
  id_test   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  id_patient    INTEGER,
  id_type_test  INTEGER, 
  id_graph  INTEGER, 
  id_graph2 INTEGER, 
  date_test VARCHAR(10),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_patient)  REFERENCES patients(id_patient) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_type_test) REFERENCES type_tests(id_type_test) ); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS type_tests  ( 
    id_type_test     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    name_test      VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO type_tests values (1,'Audi'); 
INSERT INTO type_tests values (2,'Log'); 
INSERT INTO type_tests values (3,'na'); 

INSERT INTO patients values (1,'John','5653346','john@foe.com');
INSERT INTO patients values (2,'Karla','234346','karla@foe.com');
INSERT INTO patients values (3,'Chad','6667653346','chad@foe.com');

INSERT INTO tests values (1,1,1,50,160,'02/02/2010');
INSERT INTO tests values (2,1,3,55,165,'12/05/2010');
INSERT INTO tests values (3,1,3,65,170,'03/12/2010');
```

I would like to retrieve all patient information of all patients plus their studies ordered by most recent date like:

```
ID Name Tel Email Date Test graph graph2
```

To solve that first I tried getting all studies of one patient like:

```
SELECT te.name_test AS Test,
       e.date_test AS Date,
       e.id_graph AS id_graph,
       e.id_graph2 AS id_graph2 
  FROM tests e 
       INNER JOIN type_tests te 
           ON e.id_type_test = te.id_type_test 
 WHERE e.id_patient=1 
ORDER BY 
       e.date_test DESC;
```

I got:

```
Test    Date         id_graph   id_graph2
na       12/05/2010   55    165
na       03/12/2010   65    170
Audi    02/02/2010    50    160
```

How can I get all patient information of all patients?

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/245d3/4)

desired output would be

```
ID Name Tel       Email         Test Date        id_graph id_graph2
1  John 5653346   john@foe.com  na   12/05/2010  55       165
1  John 5653346   john@foe.com  na   03/12/2010  65       170 
1  John 5653346   john@foe.com  Audi 02/02/2010  50       160
```

If there were more patients I would like to show all patients...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join the `patients` table:

```
SELECT p.ID,
       p.Name,
       p.Tel,
       p.Email,
       te.name_test AS Test,
       e.date_test AS Date, 
       e.id_graph AS id_graph,
       e.id_graph2 AS id_graph2 
  FROM tests e 
       INNER JOIN type_tests te 
           ON e.id_type_test = te.id_type_test 
       INNER JOIN patients p
           ON p.ID = e.id_patient
 WHERE e.id_patient=1 
ORDER BY
       e.date_test DESC;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/245d3/6)

Comment: That query woill work to retrieve all info for patient with ID = 1, How to get all info of all patients?

Comment: If you don't want to restrict it to id=1, just remove the `WHERE` condition.